# “call-process” hangs and does not launch the program

Tags: gnus, process

I’m dipping my toes into reading news with Gnus. I’d like to continue using the same editor as before for composing posts, so I put these forms in my gnus.el:

```lisp
(setq message-tab-body-function 'edit-in-vim)

(defun edit-in-vim ()
  (let ((filename (make-temp-file "gnus_vim_" nil ".usenet" (buffer-string))))
    (call-process "/home/bdesham/.nix-profile/bin/vim" nil nil nil filename)
    (insert-file-contents filename nil nil nil t)))
```

My intention is to do the following:

1. Write the current buffer into a new temporary file.
2. Run Vim to edit this temporary file. Wait for Vim to exit.
3. Replace the current buffer’s contents with the file’s contents.

Step 1 works fine—when I hit Tab in a message buffer, I see

> Wrote /tmp/gnus_vim_BE6h2K.usenet

at the bottom of the screen. At that point, though, Emacs hangs and won’t do anything until I type C-g. If I run `ps` during this hang, it doesn’t look like a new Vim process was created.

Am I using `call-process` wrong? Or is it not intended to be used to call programs that have their own terminal UI? How can I get this kind of external-editor functionality?

Comment: I've never used it, but maybe calling `suspend-tty` would help? Alternatively, I hear [evil-mode](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil) is supposed to be a pretty good implementation of vim.

Comment: @npostavs That is a great suggestion. It led me to `suspend-emacs`, which I turned into a solution that works exactly the way I want (see my updated answer). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that both Emacs and Vim want to control the entire screen. If I edit the function in the question to use `date` or a utility like that instead of Vim, there is no hang and the output replaces the buffer contents in the way I want.

Fortunately, Emacs has a function called [`suspend-emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Suspending-Emacs.html) which can be used to suspend Emacs, run some other command, and then (using the `fg` command built in to Unix shells) resume Emacs right where it left off. My full solution is

```lisp
(setq message-tab-body-function 'edit-in-vim)

(defun edit-in-vim ()
  (interactive "F")
  (let ((filename (make-temp-file "gnus_vim_" nil ".usenet")))
    (progn
      (save-restriction
        (widen)
        (write-region (point-min) (point-max) filename))
      (suspend-emacs (format "vim %s; fg"
                             (shell-quote-argument filename)))
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert-file-contents filename)
      (delete-file filename))))
```

This will probably only work under Unix (including e.g. macOS and Linux) due to the assumption that the shell has a `fg` command. Also note that when Vim exits, Emacs will immediately start again and continue running this function, even if you made Vim quit with a nonzero status code.

Thanks to [npostavs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/5296/npostavs) for pointing me to the `suspend-tty` function, which is related to `suspend-emacs`!

Comment: 'The use of `(format "'%s'" filename)` to quote the filename isn’t ideal' - You should use `(format "%s" (shell-quote-argument filename))` instead. Also, you can use `(delete-file filename)` instead of `(call-process "rm" nil nil nil filename)`.

Comment: @npostavs I’ve incorporated those suggestions into the answer. Thanks again!